# Creating multiple objects with different names in a loop to store in an array list

Tags: java, object, arraylist, while-loop

I am trying to create mutliple objects of a type of class I made. I then want to transfer these values into the array list. How can I create objects using a while loop that have different names. For example here is my code now, but it would only make an object of one name.

```
Customer cust = new Customer("bob", 20.0);
```

and my constructor if you want to see:

```
public Customer(String customerName, double amount)
{
    String name=customerName;
    double sale=amount;
}
```

**StoreTest class** (with main method):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StoreTest {

ArrayList<Customer> store = new ArrayList<Customer>();

public static void main (String[] args)
{
        double sale=1.0; //so the loop goes the first time
        //switch to dowhile
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("If at anytime you wish to exit" +
                ", please press 0 when asked to give " +
                "sale amount.");
        while(sale!=0)
        {
            System.out.println("Please enter the " +
                    "customer's name.");
            String theirName = input.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Please enter the " +
                    "the amount of the sale.");
            double theirSale = input.nextDouble();

            store.addSale(theirName, theirSale);
        }
        store.nameOfBestCustomer();
}

}
```

**Customer class:**

```
public class Customer {

private String name;
private double sale;

public Customer()
{

}

public Customer(String customerName, double amount)
{
    name=customerName;
    sale=amount;
}
}
```

**Store class** (has methods for messing with arraylist:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Store {

//creates Customer object and adds it to the array list
public void addSale(String customerName, double amount)
{
    this.add(new Customer(customerName, amount));
}

//displays name of the customer with the highest sale
public String nameOfBestCustomer()
{
    for(int i=0; i<this.size(); i++)
    {

    }
}
}
```

Comment: You constructor is not doing anything useful with the arguments passed.

Comment: Create a String array containing names, and when you loop to add your objects, pick a random value in this array.

Comment: What do you mean? Isn't it creating a Customer object?

Comment: Sure, but not setting any fields, only local variables.

Comment: I have other methods that can access the local variables.

Comment: Your `Customer(String, double)` constructor doesn't do anything the `Customer()` does.  They set variables scoped only to the constructor.  They're not setting class-level variables `name` or `sale`.

Comment: Is this because I put String and double before them? I declared them outside the constructor now. So annyway, do any of you know how to creat multiple objects with different names using a loop?

Comment: You can't.  You can only use some sort of a collection to do that... and yes, the problem with your constructor is the keywords `String`, and `double`, as I demonstrated in my answer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
ArrayList<Customer> custArr = new ArrayList<Customer>();
while(youWantToContinue) {
    //get a customerName
    //get an amount
    custArr.add(new Customer(customerName, amount);
}
```

For this to work... you'll have to fix your constructor...

---

Assuming your `Customer` class has variables called `name` and `sale`, your constructor should look like this:

```
public Customer(String customerName, double amount) {
    name = customerName;
    sale = amount;
}
```

---

Change your `Store` class to something more like this:

```
public class Store {

    private ArrayList<Customer> custArr;

    public new Store() {
        custArr = new ArrayList<Customer>();
    }

    public void addSale(String customerName, double amount) {
        custArr.add(new Customer(customerName, amount));
    }

    public Customer getSaleAtIndex(int index) {
        return custArr.get(index);
    }

    //or if you want the entire ArrayList:
    public ArrayList getCustArr() {
        return custArr;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! and so by doing this would the objects not have names? only the references from the array list?

Comment: Right...  instead of `myObject1`, `myObject2`, `myObject3`, they'd be `custArr.get(0)`, `custArr.get(1)`, `custArr.get(2)`, etc.  But the name is just how you reference it in code... the data stored within the objects doesn't care how you call the object...

Comment: @nhgrif Apologies, there were no answers when I posted mine :)

Comment: @m59 Mmm, maybe they appeared between you starting your answer and posting your answer.

Comment: @nhgrif Now I am getting the error "The method add(Customer) is undefined for the type Store". I have 3 classes. Store, Customer, and StoreTest. The array of Customer type is declared in the StoreTest class. The the while loop code is contained in the Store class and invoked in the StoreTest class. So how do I get rid of this error? It comes at this line: `this.add(new Customer(customerName, amount));`

Comment: Don't use `this`.  You'll have to include a lot more code for me to actually look at the full details of the error, but it's certainly related to your use of `this`.

Comment: If I shouldn't use `this` how should I change the arraylist? (the implicit parameter of the method)

Comment: Again, you'll have to provide a lot more code for me to see what you're doing... but `this` is definitely wrong unless you've subclassed `ArrayList`.

Comment: Is there a way I can post all of my code here? It's all pretty short.

Comment: Edit it into the original question.

Comment: Just posted it. Formatting got a little weird with copying and pasting. The first method in the Store class was what I was talking about.

Comment: So how would I call a method on the array list from the StoreTest class, or would I have to put the code from that class into the Store class and not have the StoreTest class?

Comment: Include a `getter` method in `Store` that will allow you to access it.  I'll edit one in.

Comment: Wouldn't I still have to put theses lines `store.addSale(theirName, theirSale);` `store.nameOfBestCustomer();` into the test Store class for them to work? (I'll probably change the name of the arraylist, too just so its less confusing with the class)

Comment: @nhgrif The problem now is I can't call any methods on the object of type Store because it is of type Store now, not an arrrayList. Do you know how to fix this? Thank you so much for the help btw.

Comment: You can make the `ArrayList` `public`, you can use `getCustArr()` which I wrote to return the entire `ArrayList`, or you can add a method to `Store`, for every method of `ArrayList` you want to use (see how `getSalesAtIndex(int index)` is essentially just an interface for the `get` method on `ArrayLists`)

Answer (score 5):

You can use this code...

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String[] names = {"First", "Second", "Third"};//You Can Add More Names
        double[] amount = {20.0, 30.0, 40.0};//You Can Add More Amount
        List<Customer> customers = new ArrayList<Customer>();
        int i = 0;
        while (i < names.length) {
            customers.add(new Customer(names[i], amount[i]));
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```